# print out letter squences in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have to write out a program in Prolog that prints out letter sequences, Implement in Prolog a predicate twist/2 for ‘twisting’ pairs of entries of a list and discarding the entries in between. More precisely,

• Interchange the 1st and 2nd entries,

• Discard the 3rd entry,

• Interchange the 4th and 5th entries,

• Discard the 6th entry and so on  as follows:

```
twist([’B’,r,a,d,f,o,r,d], T)--->
twist([’B’,r,a,d,f,o,r,d], [], y, T)--->
twist([a,d,f,o,r,d], [’B’,r], n, T)--->
twist([d,f,o,r,d], [’B’,r], y, T)--->
twist([o,r,d], [d,f,’B’,r], n, T)--->
twist([r,d], [d,f,’B’,r], y, T)--->
twist([], [r,d,d,f,’B’,r], n, T)--->
reverse([r,d,d,f,’B’,r], T)--->
T = [r,’B’,f,d,d,r] ---> success
```

So far I have:

```
twist(L,T) :-
   twist(L, [], y, T).  % clause 0: invoke auxiliary predicate

twist([], Acc, L)       :- reverse(Acc, L),
twist(A,G,_|T), Acc, L) :- twist(T,[A,G|Acc], L),
twist([A,G], Acc, L)    :- twist([],[A,G|Acc], L),
twist([], Acc, L)       :- reverse(Acc, L).
```

I'm sure that's right but i keep getting the same error.

here's the full error message:

```
 4 ?- twist([b, r ,a ,d ,f ,o ,r ,d], T).
 ERROR: twist/2: Undefined procedure: twist/4
 ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
 ERROR:         twist/2
 Exception: (7) twist([b, r, a, d, f, o, r, d], [], y, _G2583) ?
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: A few prologers. No clairvoyants. Your question is very unclear about what your predicate is really supposed to do. The error message you show in your comment is incomplete. And your code is very poorly formatted and difficult to read.

Comment: What I have to do is:   Implement in Prolog a predicate twist/2 for ‘twisting’ pairs of entries of a list
and discarding the entries in between. More precisely,
• Interchange the 1st and 2nd entries,
• Discard the 3rd entry,
• Interchange the 4th and 5th entries,
• Discard the 6th entry and so on

Comment: here's the full error message:  `                                                                    4 ?- twist([b, r ,a ,d ,f ,o ,r ,d], T).
     ERROR: twist/2: Undefined procedure: twist/4
     ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
     ERROR:         twist/2
     Exception: (7) twist([b, r, a, d, f, o, r, d], [], y, _G2583) ? `

Comment: Your indentation was probably OK, but the StackExchange app on my Android evidently got confused over it. My apologies. You should add your explanation to your question by editing it, not as a comment. Otherwise, other folks are going to miss it. And, yes, that's the full error message. The *undefined procedure twist/4* is the critical part that was missing in your first comment. You should add the full error message to the question as well.

Comment: The error message means your predicate is calling `twist` with 4 arguments, but nowhere do you have `twist` *defined* with 4 arguments.

Comment: OK here are a few hints. First, you don't need `reverse` or anything like that. You just need to make logical *rules*, which are *predicate clauses* for `twist`. Write the simple ones first. Since things only get interesting when you have 3 list elements, you probably want a special base case for 0, 1, or 2 list elements. For 0 elements, you would have `twist([], ??).` For one element, `twist([X], ??).` and for two you'd have `twist([X,Y], ??).` You determine what `??` needs to be in these cases. Then write a general rule, `twist([X,Y,Z|T], ??) :- ...` for what to do in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
twist([],[]).
twist([X],[X]).
twist([X,Y],[Y,X]).
twist([X,Y,_|Tail],[Y,X|NewTail]):- twist(Tail, NewTail).
```

And then ask:

```
?- twist([b, r ,a ,d ,f ,o ,r ,d], T).
T = [r, b, f, d, d, r] ;
false.
```

credits go to @lurker.